# Error while Multiplying a u64 to u128 in Rust?

Tags: rust

I want to multiply a u128 number with a u64 number. u64 will always be less than or equal to one. Amount is always greater than 1000000(1 million)

```
fn testing(amount:u128, starting_time:u64, ending_time:u64, duration:u64){
return amount*((ending_time - starting_time:u64)/duration) 
}
```

Even if the number should return something like 500,000 it always returns zero unless the `((ending_time - starting_time:u64)/duration)` equals 1 then the return value always amounts.

I want to give less weightage to someone if they enter the last to the lottery. Both starting and ending times are u64 because they are in UNIX timestamps.

Example: Let's say Alice entered the lottery at time 0. Same time the lottery was started. So Alice would get full weightage for the amount she deposited let's say she deposited 30000 so she will get 30000 tickets.

Bob entered the lottery halfway through the lottery means that whatever he deposits he will get half the weightage of the deposited amount. If he deposits 30000 he will get 15000 tickets.

Comment: what does u128 mean? why can't you use u64 throughout the function?

Comment: Actually the values are fixed I can't change the values

Comment: "*u64 will always be less than or equal to one*" - you mean it's always zero or one (i.e. `bool`)? Since `u64` is an *unsigned* *integer* type, it can't store anything less than zero or between one and zero...

Comment: Yes you're diving integers so the result of `(ending_time - starting_time:u64)/duration` will always be rounded down to the nearest integer. You should convert to floats first to get around this.

Comment: Jacob makes a good point. if you are using division, you probably want to use floats instead of ints?

Comment: It would also help if you gave an example of the actual numbers you are passing into the function, your expected results and your actual results.

Comment: Or multiply first and divide afterwards: `(amount*(ending_time - starting_time))/duration` (change that to `(amount*(ending_time - starting_time) + duration/2)/duration` if you wan to round to nearest instead of always rounding down). Note however that this may overflow if your numbers are too big.

Comment: @Rick added example

Comment: @Jmb amount is in u128. Can't multiply with u64

Comment: Just cast your `u64` to `u128`: `(amount*(ending_time - starting_time) as u128)/duration as u128`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I found is:

```
(amount/1000000) * ((  ((end_time  - start_time)*1000000  )/duration ) as u128)
```

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 problems with your code:

1. You are trying to subtract 2 timestamps, but is that going to leave you with a timestamp? or a number? and if it is the number, is that in seconds or milliseconds or what? and does duration also represent seconds or milliseconds or is it another timestamp?

If all that code still makes sense, then you have a second problem:

2. Your expression: `ending_time - starting_time)/duration`, presumably you are expecting it to be a fraction between 0 & 1, right? well if all your variables are ints, then your result is going to be an int, which means guess what? no fraction.

You need to cast all that stuff to floats, or multiply the amount first so you don't have to worry about the fraction. Maybe try this:

```
return amount*(ending_time - starting_time)/duration;
```